# Why does my "import requests" fail with ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'?

Tags: python

This has happened both on OS X, and Linux.  Unfortunately I don't have the exact repro steps, but that's OK because I'm about to answer my own question below.

Here's a typical failure:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 83, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't even explain *why*, but the problem was due to my having a file named "email.py" in my current directory.  I renamed that to something else, and suddenly everything started working again.

By sticking a "breakpoint" (i.e., a deliberate divide-by-zero error) into that file, we can see who was importing it:

`(venv):) 14:36:46 [erichanchrow@Eric-Hanchrows-iMac rack_assigner] (refunds *)$ python -c 'import refund'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "refund.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 63, in load_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/Users/erichanchrow/git-repositories/rack_assigner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 1, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "email.py", line 11, in <module>
    5/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

Comment: `email` is the name of a built-in module that `requests` seems to rely on. It looks like `requests` tried to import `email`, got an error, and made a bad assumption about the cause of the error.