# Mysterious "'module' object has no attribute" error

Tags: python, pyramid

Every time I try to serve my project I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pserve", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 313, in run
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 344, in loadserver
    server_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 255, in loadserver
    return loadobj(SERVER, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py3.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2320, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2326, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from waitress.server import create_server
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/server.py", line 23, in <module>
    from waitress.channel import HTTPChannel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 28, in <module>
    from waitress.task import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/task.py", line 53, in <module>
    class ThreadedTaskDispatcher(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py3.4.egg/waitress/task.py", line 57, in ThreadedTaskDispatcher
    start_new_thread = thread.start_new_thread
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start_new_thread'
```

The weird thing is, the thread module has the attribute `start_new_thread`

```
>>> from waitress.compat import (thread, Empty)
>>> thread.start_new_thread
<built-in function start_new_thread>
```

I started this pyramid project using python 2.7, and I am trying to switch it over to python 3.4.

Things I've tried:

- updating the waitress module, it's already up to date
- scratching my head

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 3.4 in your second code?

Comment: Sounds like you're being bit by [the same bug that got me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730964/why-does-my-import-requests-fail-with-importerror-no-module-named-requests-p).